# Product of all positive odd numbers

Tags: infinity, regularization

I am looking for simplest regularisation of infinite product:
$$
\prod^{\infty}_{k≥0} (2k+1) = ??
$$

Comment: Yes, so I wanna regularise this

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233175/zeta-regularization-of-infinite-product

Answer (score 1):

A non-rigorous methode, the answer seems correct, but because of the link in the comments I doubt everything I did, because i would make the same mistake the question asker asked there (I think).

$$\prod_{k=1}^{m}(2k-1)=\exp(\sum_{k=1}^{m}ln(2k-1))$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}ln(2k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}ln(2k)$$

Then based upon linearity, if regularised for m $(S\infty)$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2m}ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}ln(k)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{S\infty}ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^{S\infty}ln(k)=0 $$
And with zeta(0)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{S\infty}ln(2)=\frac{-ln(2)}{2}$$

Thuse 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{S\infty}ln(2k-1)=\frac{ln(2)}{2}$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^{S\infty}(2k-1)=\sqrt{2}$$